# What's wrong with my python code (Add binary)?

Tags: python

It's a very simple problem from leetcode:

> Given two binary strings, return their sum (also a binary string).
>
> For example, a = "11" b = "1" Return "100".

Here is my code, I think it's just okay

```
def addBinary(self, a, b):
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a, b = b, a
            
    rev, temp, sum = list(a[::-1]), 0, ""
        
    for i, j in enumerate(b[::-1]):
        temp = temp + int(rev[i]) + int(j)
        if temp == 0 or 1:
            rev[i] = str(temp)
            temp = 0
            x2 = temp
        elif temp == 2:
            rev[i] = "0"
            temp = 1
            
    if temp == 1:
        rev = rev + ["1"]
        
    for digit in rev[::-1]:
        sum += digit
        
    return sum
```

However as I run, a test can't pass

> Input:    "1", "1"
>
> Output:   "2"
>
> Expected: "10"

I simply don't know why and set a break point, finding that though "temp = temp + int(rev[i]) + int(j)", temp was equalled to 2, it didn't go to the elif part of the condition and thus returns "2" as the final result.

Could anyone tell me why? I really appreciate that.

Comment: `if temp == 0 or 1:` doesn't do what you think it does. See the dupe for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
if temp == 0 or 1:
```

should instead be:

```
if temp == 0 or temp == 1:
```

Comment: thanks a lot, maybe I should ( ) them as well

Comment: `if temp in (0,1)` is nice, too.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and more pythonic way of doing the same is:

```
def add_binary(a, b):
    return bin(int(a) + int(b))[2:]

print add_binary("1", "1")
>>> 10
```

Comment: @PaulSasik: No, it's supposed to be "10". "100" is the expected output for inputs "11" and "1".

Comment: @PaulSasik you are doubting on Python binary arithmetic ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal: No, I'm doubting why you chose a different set of input than the OP?

Comment: @PaulSasik: Look further down in the question. "1" and "1" is the specific failing test case.

Comment: @PaulSasik Because the OP had given 2 sample inputs and I just tried out the latter one, read the bottom line of the question.

Comment: Long day. Sorry guys. What's the down vote about? I didn't run it but your code seem legit.

Comment: Don't worry it happens, and comments from downvoters ?